# Expand ENV variable of a string, run command and store in variable?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I expand a variable, run that command and store output to variable?

Usually you do this

```
var="$(echo string)"
```

but I want this

```
envString='echo $stringToEcho'
stringToEcho="hello world"
var="$(${envString})"`
```

But the dollar sign inside doesn't expand. I need to run a command stored in a variable and store the output to another variable.

Comment: Also, running a command stored in a scalar variable (as opposed to an array) is exceedingly bad practice and inherently buggy (without `eval`) or prone to security failures (with `eval`). See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: To evaluate the variable, you need `var=$($envString)`. But see @CharlesDuffy's remark about bad practices.

Comment: I've edited this per clarification of your actual question in comments. If you'd care to speak as to whether that editing was appropriate/on-target, such comment would be appreciated.

Comment: @chrisaycock, `var=$($envString)` skips all parsing steps prior to string-splitting, so it doesn't do parameter expansion (or honor quotes/redirections/etc); hence it echo'ing `$stringToEcho` rather than `hello world` here. Granted, the way the OP first wrote the question, it wasn't clear that that was their actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string contains content which was written to be `eval`-safe:

```
envString="echo string"
var=$(eval "$envString")
```

...which will work even if it includes variable references, if quoting correctly:

```
envString='echo "$someVar"'  # use single-quotes here to avoid premature expansion!
someVar='hello world'
var=$(eval "$envString")
```

However, if your string contains contents generated by expanding variables without using `printf %q` to safely escape any variables contained, **do not do this**.

---

References:

- [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")
- [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) ("Eval command and security issues").

Comment: Yes it does command contents generated with a variable inside the string as well. i.e envString="echo ${stringToEcho}"

Comment: When you use double-quotes, you're causing the expansion to take place *at assignment time*, not evaluation time.

Comment: ...thus, you're looking at the value of `stringToEcho` when you run `envString="echo ${stringToEcho}"`, not when you run `eval "$envString"`.

Comment: Need I point out that if that's your actual bug, _you didn't actually include code that reproduced it in your question_?

Comment: code is sensitive which is why I didnt so I substituted it for an example

Comment: Sure, but you need to test that your example **actually reproduces the problem you're asking about**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for.